# Looking Bitwise solution for this

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

> You’re given a read only array of n integers. Find out if any integer occurs more than n/3 times in the array in linear time and constant additional space.
>
> If so, return the integer. If not, return -1.
>
> If there are multiple solutions, return any one.
>
> Example :
>
> ```
> Input : [1 2 3 1 1]
> Output : 1
> ```
>
> 1 occurs 3 times which is more than 5/3 times.

I've solved this problem and found some solutions for this on google. But I want a bitwise approach. If you could help me, I'd appreciate it.

Solution without bitwise:

```
int Solution::repeatedNumber(const vector<int> &A)
{
    int len = A.size();
    if (A.size() == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if (A.size() == 1)
    {
        return A[0];
    }
    int c1 = A[0];
    int c2 = A[1];
    int c1count = 0;
    int c2count = 0;

    for(int num: A)
    {
        if(c1 == num)
        {
            c1count++;
        }
        else if(c2 == num)
        {
            c2count++;
        }
        else if(c1count == 0)
        {
            c1 = num;
            c1count = 1;
        }

        else if(c2count == 0)
        {
            c2 = num;
            c2count = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            c1count--;
            c2count--;
        }
    }

    c1count = 0;
    c2count = 0;
    for(int num : A)
    {
        if(c1 == num)
        {
            c1count++;
        }
        else if(num == c2)
        {
            c2count++;
        }
    }

    if(c1count > len/3)
    {
        return c1;
    }
    else if(c2count > len/3)
    {
        return c2;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the approaches that you've already found?

Comment: They are based on Moore’s Voting algorithm. Should I give the link?

Comment: No, paste your code into the question as text.

Comment: I can't edit. Shows error that indentation is not okay, even though I indented the code using both Sublime and VSCode.

Comment: After pasting the code here, select the code, and click the code button `{}`.

Comment: Done. Now is it okay for them to open the question?

Comment: I voted to reopen, but after reading about Moore's voting algorithm, and looking at the code, I don't see how a bitwise solution helps in this case. Bitwise solutions to problems like this typically depend on some magic using XOR operations. I don't see how that could be used in this case. Did you have some other bitwise operations in mind?

Comment: Nope, I also thought of XOR, tried to do it, didn't work. One of my senior programmers told me it could be solved by bitwise, but I couldn't solve and don't agree with him. So I thought maybe if I could get help from here. Thanks for the trouble you took.

Comment: Which information do you think can be stored in the bits?